# Session Authentication in Next.js web app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

I am currently imlementing the NextAuth authentication in a React.js web application I am working on. In an effort to allow the user's authentication accross the entire app, I am trying to wrap a SessionProvider around the root component. Alas, VSCode is throwing an error, asserting that the 'session' property does not exist. I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.
Thx.

```
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What is your NextJS version? Are you using App Router or Pages Router?

Comment: @MohamedEl-Refaie I'm using 12.3.4. Would an upgrade to 14 fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AppProps` type does not include the injected `session` object, so you have to extend it and create a new type:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { Session } from 'next-auth';

type AppPropsWithSession = AppProps & {
  pageProps: {
    session?: Session;
  };
};

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithSession) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```